# jQuery Ajax - sometimes I get a response, sometimes no response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

this is my Ajax function (for polling), wrapped in `$(document).ready`. Every second, a request should be sent to `update.php`.

(Note that `getParameterByName` and `arrayIndexExists` are my own functions)

```
(function poll() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "../update.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {"game": getParameterByName("game")},
                dataType: "json",
                complete: poll,         
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("Updating");
                    console.log(data);                      
                }                   
            });
        }, 1000);
    })();
```

This is what I have here in `update.php`:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$game = $_POST["game"];
$returnArray = array();
// do stuff with the data......
echo json_encode($returnArray);
```

---

When it works (say 60% of the time), something like this appears in the console every second or so:

[image: console1]

But when it doesn't work, nothing appears in the console at all.

Apparently, the request is still being sent, just that there is no response:

[image: console2]

I had spent the whole morning yesterday trying to figure out the problem but I don't know what I'm doing wrong and how to get it working 100% of the time. Thanks.

Comment: If you're not getting a response, there's some problem with your server.

Comment: Check the PHP or Apache log on the server.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, which log are you referring to? Currently im using XAMPP (localhost), are you talking about `\xampp\apache\logs\error.log` ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the specific log file location in XAMPP. That sounds like it might be the right place.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure what I should be looking out for in the log, but I found there are a lot of such errors :`[Fri Dec 11 08:58:06.638165 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 6524:tid 408] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name` I'm not too sure what it really means though.

Comment: Will increasing the `setTimeout` delay from `1000` to `2000` (or more) help? *(edit: just tried it out, still not getting response sometimes)*

Comment: That warning means there's a problem with the SSL certificate you have loaded, it doesn't have your correct domain in it. But I don't think it's related to the problem. Is there any error that only shows up when you get the empty response?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why changing the delay would make a difference, but what happens when you try it?

Comment: @Barmar No error shows up in the log when I'm not getting a response. I'm using `setTimeout` for the polling because `complete: poll` in the ajax request will run the function (and the ajax request) one second after the request is complete. Changing the delay didn't make any difference unfortunately :(